# Not able to compare variables in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of records. I want to search a string at the specific position of the array. But some how I am not able to do so. Kindly see the code below:

```
var match_index = [];
var count = 0;
var keyword1 = csvvalue[1][9].replace(/\"/g, '');
var search_text="इलाहाबाद";
$("#leng").html(csvvalue.length);
for(var i=0; i<csvvalue.length; i++){
   $("#index").html("loop");
   var keyword1 = csvvalue[i][9].replace(/\"/g, '');                    
   if (search_text === keyword1)
   {
      match_index[count] = i;
      count++;
      $("#index").html("match");
   }
   $("#index").append("<br />" + i.toString());
}
```

In the above code, the control is is not going inside the `if` statement, though the string is available in the array at index 1 and 2. Also only the last value of `i` is getting printed (last line of the code) though it should print all the values of `i` starting from `0`.

My actual requirement is to search through entire array for a specific string. I have changed the code to suit my requirement better.

**Edited**

I tried every thing but the control is not going inside the if statement though there are two matching records

Comment: It's because you're replacing the contents with the text "loop" at the start of the every iteration, and with "match" every time there's a match.

Comment: @Juhana, Thank you very much. I fixed that. But please help me with the main issue

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two values set before the loop

I guess it should be more like :

```
var match_index = [];
var count = 0;
var keyword1 = "";
var search_text="इलाहाबाद";
$("#leng").html(csvvalue.length);
for(var i=0; i<csvvalue.length; i++){
   keyword1 = csvvalue[i].replace(/\"/g, '');
   $("#index").html("loop");                    
   if (search_text === keyword1)
   {
      match_index[count] = i;
      count++;
      $("#index").html("match");
   }
   $("#index").append("<br />" + i.toString());
}
```

Or depending on how your csvvalue array is structured.

`keyword1 = csvvalue[1][i].replace(/\"/g, '');`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, even doing this inside the loop reflects no change. My actual requirement is the same as I need to compare entire array so the index must be a variable.

Comment: @user3405976: Don't tell me (just the editor)... tell the person who answered it :)

Comment: @user3405976 : Could you tell us more, how is your array like ?

Comment: @BastienSander, I am converting a csv file into array. The array contains records of organizations. It is a multidimensional array consisting one record per index. I need to search it for different keywords like location. The array is working fine and it is displaying the records and I can even access individual records or even items of individual records (multidimensional array). Thank you!

Comment: So don't you need two loops like   `for (i in csvalue) { for (j in csvalue[i]) { if (kayword === csvvalue[i][j]){ //test true } }}` ?

Comment: @BastienSander, No! Because i know the inner index number of the multidimensional array. So I don't need two loops

Comment: ok, if you log the values to the console, are you sure they are exactly equal ? Don't you need a specific charset for those characters ?

Comment: @BastienSander, The values are exactly equal. I copied the search value from the csv file itself. I am using Unicode/UTF-8 to display the characters in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why loop through the whole array if you want to check a specific variable in the array.
You could just do something like

> if (search_text === csvvalue[1][9].replace(/\"/g, '') { 
>   //do something 
>   }

Unless you really need to know how many times you run through the array.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but my actual requirement is to search through entire array. The above code is just for a demo

Comment: So you want to search the array for a specific keyword in that array? Basically finding duplicates?